# Isolating cookies between subdomains

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, cookies, subdomain

Given the three URLs

- http://example.com
- http://subsite.example.com
- http://admin.subsite.example.com

I would like the browser to be able to set their own cookies from any given URL such that the other two URLs are unaware of those cookies (i.e. can't be read or modified by JavaScript from the other two).

All three of the URLs go to the same location by creating a virtual server for `example.com` and using Apache's `ServerAlias *.example.com`.  HTTP_HOST as seen by the server (as read by PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, etc) must provide enough information so that the server could determine which of the three URLs the browser is pointing to.

Without any type of rewrite, browser pointing to http://admin.subsite.example.com will have access to cookies set by http://example.com and http://subsite.example.com.

Is this possible through mod-rewrite or other means to keep cookies isolated between these three subdomains?  If so, please explain how to do so.

EDIT.  I was thinking of something like the following, but I don't know if it makes any sense.  Also, I didn't state so in my OP, but "subsite" is just an example of one possible value, and it might be "bobs_site", etc.

- http://example.com is rewritten to http://sd1.example.com
- http://subsite.example.com is rewritten to http://subsite.sd2.example.com
- http://admin.subsite.example.com is rewritten to  - http://admin.subsite.sd3.example.com

Comment: Setting cookies on `example.com` will make them available to the other two; setting cookies on `subsite.example.com` will make them available to `admin.subsite.example.com`; but JavaScript access can be disabled using [HttpOnly cookies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly).

Comment: @Ja͢ck By doing so, can each subdomain access cookies set within that subdomain still with JavaScript?

Comment: Well, setting a cookie with JavaScript is not something that HttpOnly was meant to prevent and [allegedly](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/cookies-httponly-flag-problem-browsers/) some browsers allow setting cookies that override the HttpOnly cookies.

Comment: Does my idea of rewriting make any sense?  My concern is it might be rewritten to the server, but the client just sees the same as before the rewrite...